# Django admin.py ValueError when trying to save manytomany field

Tags: python, django, django-admin, many-to-many, django-orm

I am trying to create a model with a manytomany field in Django, and using the default admin.py interface I am getting a ValueError: needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

I understand that you need to save the instance before a many-to-many field can be populated because it is a separate table, however I am not manually saving but instead relying on admin.py. I have a separate model in my app that has a many-to-many field that saves normally in admin.py so I am  unsure where the problem is

My models code is:

```
class CaseFeature(models.Model):
"""Case-specific history features"""
    case = models.ForeignKey(
            Case, 
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
            related_name="features",
            db_index=True)
    feature_name = models.ForeignKey(
            CoreFeature, 
            on_delete=models.PROTECT,
            db_index=True)
    response = models.TextField("Patient Response", max_length=500)
    clerking_text = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    tooltip = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    important = models.BooleanField()
    answered_clarifying_qs = models.ManyToManyField(CoreClarifying, blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        # Make sure answered_clarifying are valid for this symptom
        if self.answered_clarifying_qs not in self.feature_name.clarifying_qs:
            raise ValidationError(_('Answered clarifying Qs do not match this symptom'))


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.case} - {self.feature_name}"
```

My admin.py is: (nothing changes when I comment this out I still get a value error)

```
class CaseFeatureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':5})}
    }
...
admin.site.register(CaseFeature, CaseFeatureAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to the clean method which occurs before saving. The solution was to move the clean validation rules to the ModelForm instead which worked!